# How do I loop through the API from coinmarketcap line after line with python?

Tags: python

I never worked with API, and I am also new to python, but I want to loop through the API from coinmarketcap, line per line

I get the api through this code:

```
requests = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
```

I tried doing it by just doing

```
for line in requests:
```

but that doesn't seem to work how I want it

Eventually I want to put all the symbols, marketcaps and volumes in all sperate lists, and combine them so I can call the marketcap and volume from any symbol.

Comment: Requests.get returns a Response object, which is not iterable. Are you trying to get lines, or JSON?

Comment: I'm trying to get lines, I managed to iterate through it though?

Comment: You can't extract any useful information from single lines. You need to parse the JSON that's returned

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm new to programming so I didn't even know what JSON was, but that seems the thing I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: I see that you have Javascript questions, so I assumed you already knew that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, that API returns JSON.

Secondly, you're overriding the `requests` module import by setting variable to the same name

Try this

```
import json 
import requests 

r = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/')
for coin in r.json():
    print(coin)
```